# headings display block a line with text

Tags: css, text, html-heading

here my website 
http://maximearchambault.com/index.php/contact/

My question is regarding one of my headings. 
I use it for the main title of the page, contact / info

My problem is  the block is not a line with the text.
I will like that the text will be centered with the cyan block

```
h2 { font-size: 30px;  
     font-weight: bold; 
     background: #00FFFF; 
     width: 600px;
     HEIGHT: 33px; 
     display: block; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `line-height:33px;` to your `h2 {... }`

```
h2 { font-size: 30px;  
     font-weight: bold; 
     background: #00FFFF; 
     width: 600px;
     HEIGHT: 33px; 
     display: block; 
     line-height:33px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change:

```
display: block;
```

to:

```
display: inline;
```

Also remember that CSS is case-sensitive so HEIGHT is not a valid property.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your css to:

```
h2{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #00FFFF;
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 33px;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    text-align:center;
    width: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like;

```
h2 {
    font-size: 30px;  
    font-weight: bold; 
    background: #00FFFF;
    width: 600px;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;   
}
```

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/maHQJ/)*** is the working Live Demo.

Answer (score 0):

```
h2 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #00FFFF;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 600px;
 }

 1. Remove the properly "display: block" from h2 class properties because h2 is block element
 2. Add a property - "text-align: center"
```